# jQuery show/hide div from bottom to top

Tags: jquery

Yo all!

I am new with jQuery and I want to know how can I show/hide a div using fadeIn and FadeOut and at the same time an animation bottom to top and top to bottom.

I tried with this: http://jsfiddle.net/jalxob/kNL5m/2/

But it also shows a {"error": "Please use POST request"}

Can anyone please help me?

```
$('.hello').click(function() {
$(".content_b").fadeIn();
$(".content_b_content").animate({marginTop:"-=100px"},300);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use a `hash` as the href attribute of the both anchor tags like this, But keep in mind that using `#` as the `href` attribute will cause the page to `bump` back to the `top`.

```
<a href="#" class="hello">Show It</a>
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/kNL5m/6/)

Or another good work around will be like this, Just void the action of the particular anchor tags by providing the href attribute as `javascript:void(0)` like this,

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="hello">Show It</a>
```

### [DEMO I](http://jsfiddle.net/kNL5m/10/)

Answer (score 2):

You just need [`e.preventDefault()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/) or add `#` to your `<a href='#'></a>` tag

```
$('.hello').click(function(e) {
         e.preventDefault();
        $(".content_b").fadeIn();
        $(".content_b_content").animate({marginTop:"-=100px"},300);
});

$('.goodbye').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(".content_b").fadeOut();
        $(".content_b_content").fadeOut();
});
```

[**Updated Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/kNL5m/4/)

Answer (score 0):

Write:

```
<span class="hello">Show It</span> //No need of link as you are animating divs on click
<span class="goodbye">Show It</span>
```

Instead of

```
<a href="" class="hello">Show It</a>
<a href="" class="goodbye">Show It</a>
```

CSS:

```
.hello,.goodbye{cursor:pointer;}
```

[**Updated fiddle here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/kNL5m/9/)

Comment: Technically you now have a placeholder and not a real anchor in HTML5, in any other doctype you have invalid markup, and I'm not sure removing the href attribute is the best idea ?

Answer (score 0):

Use the # in the href attribute. [Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/blackpanther/kNL5m/8/) This is because you need the `null` value to take the user to the same page he was on.

Also, I changed the `click()` to `on("click", function())`